# update UI by calling AsyncTask objects many times

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am making simple app , that display questions , the user within 10 seconds should answer or click next, when user click next , next question is displayed and the timer goes again to 10 seconds.
i am using Asytask to handle the time counter , but when i click next button , the next question is displayed but the timer delay like 2 seconds or so to start again from 10 ,
for example:
on the screen : question 1 is displayed and the time left is 8 seconds .
when i click next button 
the question 2 is displayed but the time is 8 then after 2 or 3 seconds the time goes to 10 and start decreasing :
my question is :
is there a better way to handle this ? and why is when the next question is displayed it the time hang like  2 or 3 seconds then start again from 10 
here is my code :

```
    // this method is called to reset the timer to 10 and display next 
    question

  private void displynextquestion(){
  // cancel the current thread .

     decrease_timer.cancel(true);     
   decrease_timer =new Decrease_timer();
   // execute again and set the timer to 10 seconds
   decrease_timer.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,10);
   // some code 
    }
     private class Decrease_timer extends AsyncTask <Integer ,Integer,Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

    for (int i=integers[0];i>=0;i--){
        publishProgress(i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    timeview.setText(""+values[0]);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CountDownTimer, is much more easy:

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
};
```

The first argument in the CountDownTimer constructor is the total time in milliseconds, and the second argument is the interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks.

To restart, just call:

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
countDownTimer.start();
```

See more in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html